# replace quote only in font family

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML,

```
"Hi this is vishal&quot;s code <span style='font-family:&quot;arial black&quot;'>vishal</span>". I want to remove &quot; of font-family and want to keep quot; of vishal as it is. I want to change it using jquery.
```

When I apply font-family with mulitple words radeditor applies `&quot;` to it, I read that HTML from radeditor and paste it in my textbox. that time I want to change this using jQuery.

How I can do that? please help.

Comment: So... what are you saying? You want to replace `&quot;` with `"`?

Comment: In font-family I can remove that &quot; and it will work smoothly. if I will replace it with " it will break. so basically I want to remove &quot; but only from font-family and not all HTML

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is:

```
yourText.match(/'font-family(.*)'/)[0].replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

More info about `replace` function in this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the `"` when doing a replace `yourText.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');`

Comment: but as i said I don't want to replace it in first place. i want to replace it when its with font-family. as when I try to open same HTML in radeditor later. it breaks. which I don't want.

Comment: I added using `match` for `font-family` search